# Can not discard all changes XCode

Tags: xcode, git

2 and we are working on a shared GitHub Project.

Sadly I uploaded the UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate file to GitHub.
My Partner just uploaded a version of our App witch works fine but makes it impossible for me to make changes. When I try to commit and push it failed because "The local repository is out of date" which makes sense. So I discard all changes and try to pull. But pulling fails because I make changes in UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate right after I discard changes.

So basically I need to remove UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate from my GitHub upload.

I tried to delete the file on GitHub webend which worked but doesn't solve the problem.
Then I tried to do something with the .gitignore file. I generated one by using touch .gitignore but I sadly don't find the file and even when I don't know exactly what to do with it.

Comment: Have you done a `git rm UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate`?

Comment: @esqew I am not quite sure how to do that? Do i need to go to the folder with cd [myFolder] or not? And do I need to type the whole path after git rm or just UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `git` is already tracking the file, adding it to the `.gitignore` won't do much - you'll need to remove it from being tracked first.

---

Firstly, in Terminal, `cd` to your project directory and run `git status`. If there's any file *aside* from your UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate that's changed, you'll likely want to save a copy of that file before continuing.

With Xcode closed, do a hard reset to roll back any changes that you might have made from your last pull/commit. (**Note**: this *will* erase anything you've been working on in that time, although from the text of your question it seems as though you're alright with this).

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

From there, ensure `git` will no longer track your UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate file:

```
git rm --cached <path>/<to>/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
```

Then, commit and push the change to origin:

```
git commit -m "Removed file that shouldn't be tracked"
git push origin <branchname>
```